# Define a field with 256 elements

Tags: code-golf, abstract-algebra

A [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) in mathematics is a set of numbers, with addition and multiplication operations defined on it, such that they satisfy certain axioms (described in Wikipedia; see also below).

A finite field can have p<sup>n</sup> elements, where `p` is a prime number, and `n` is a natural number. In this challenge, let's take `p = 2` and `n = 8`, so let's make a field with 256 elements.

The elements of the field should be consecutive integers in a range that contains `0` and `1`:

- -128 ... 127
- 0 ... 255
- or any other such range

Define *two* functions (or programs, if that is easier), `a(x,y)` for abstract "addition", and `m(x,y)` for abstract "multiplication", such that they satisfy the field axioms:

- Consistency: `a(x,y)` and `m(x,y)` produce the same result when called with same arguments
- Closedness: The result of `a` and `m` is an integer in the relevant range
- Associativity: for any `x`, `y` and `z` in the range, `a(a(x,y),z)` is equal to `a(x,a(y,z))`; the same for `m`
- Commutativity: for any `x` and `y` in the range, `a(x,y)` is equal to `a(y,x)`; the same for `m`
- Distributivity: for any `x`, `y` and `z` in the range, `m(x,a(y,z))` is equal to `a(m(x,y),m(x,z))`
- Neutral elements: for any `x` in the range, `a(0,x)` is equal to `x`, and `m(1,x)` is equal to `x`
- Negation: for any `x` in the range, there exists such `y` that `a(x,y)` is `0`
- Inverse: for any `x≠0` in the range, there exists such `y` that `m(x,y)` is `1`

The names `a` and `m` are just examples; you can use other names, or unnamed functions. The score of your answer is the sum of byte-lengths for `a` and `m`.

If you use a built-in function, please also describe in words which result it produces (e.g. provide a multiplication table).

Comment: @LeakyNun "addition" is just an abstract operation here that satisfies the above properties. There is no need for `a(2,1) = 3`, you could have `a(2,1) = 5` as long as the above axioms are satisfied. `a` doesn't have to do anything with the usual addition you're used to e.g. from the field of rational numbers.

Comment: A commutative ring is trivial. A field... not so easy.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `a=+` `m=×`?

Comment: @Adám Yes - 2 wouldn't have an inverse if `m=×`

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9276/194)

Comment: I am eagerly waiting for an INTERCAL example.

Comment: Well, I know what addition is, it's just multiplication that's the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Intel x86-64 + AVX-512 + GFNI, 11 bytes

```
add:
    C5 F0 57 C0     # vxorps     xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
    C3              # ret
mul:
    C4 E2 79 CF C1  # vgf2p8mulb xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
    C3              # ret
```

Uses the new `GF2P8MULB` instruction on Ice Lake CPUs.

> The instruction multiplies elements in the finite field GF(2<sup>8</sup>), operating on a byte (field element) in the first source operand and the corresponding byte in a second source operand. The field GF(2<sup>8</sup>) is represented in polynomial representation with the reduction polynomial x<sup>8</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + x + 1.

Answer (score 12):

### Python 2, 11 + 45 = 56 bytes

**Addition** (11 bytes):

```py
int.__xor__
```

**Multiplication** (45 bytes):

```py
m=lambda x,y:y and m(x*2^x/128*283,y/2)^y%2*x
```

Takes input numbers in the range `[0 ... 255]`. Addition is just bitwise XOR, multiplication is multiplication of polynomials with coefficients in GF2 with [Russian peasant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic).

And for checking:

```py
a=int.__xor__
m=lambda x,y:y and m(x*2^x/128*283,y/2)^y%2*x

for x in range(256):
    assert a(0,x) == a(x,0) == x
    assert m(1,x) == m(x,1) == x

    assert any(a(x,y) == 0 for y in range(256))

    if x != 0:
        assert any(m(x,y) == 1 for y in range(256))

    for y in range(256):
        assert 0 <= a(x,y) < 256
        assert 0 <= m(x,y) < 256
        assert a(x,y) == a(y,x)
        assert m(x,y) == m(y,x)

        for z in range(256):
            assert a(a(x,y),z) == a(x,a(y,z))
            assert m(m(x,y),z) == m(x,m(y,z))
            assert m(x,a(y,z)) == a(m(x,y), m(x,z))
```

Comment: One of us is going to have to change :P

Comment: @Mego Hah, well... I'll try and see if I can find any other approaches. Might be hard to beat though.

Comment: No worries. I'm actually going to delete mine, since this is golfier, and I trust that you actually came up with this solution on your own and weren't trying to steal my solution :P

Comment: Which polynomial is it based on?

Comment: @feersum, indeed, I guess that `283` in the definition of the multiplication is encoding the polynomial somehow, but I'd be very interested to know whence it came!

Comment: @LSpice Now I realize that I can easily find the polynomial by running `m(2,128)` which results in 27 = 283 - 256, so you are correct and the polynomial is `x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1`.

Comment: @feersum, clever!  I guess that this polynomial must be published somewhere as the 'standard' one for GF(256), since it seems that [@Neil](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82875/17788) is using the same one.

Comment: @LSpice In Neil's answer he gives a Wikipedia page as a source for the algorithm, so maybe everyone read that. But it is anyway the most obvious choice for code golf since it the smallest irreducible polynomial of degree 8 in this representation.

Comment: @feersum I got 283 from the Wikipedia page too, but I also ran a search for a shorter modulus. There are no moduli for GF(256) that are shorter than 3 digits (unless I did something wrong in my calculations), so 283 is as good of a modulus as any.

Comment: @Mego Surely all moduli for GF(256) must lie between 256 and 512?

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 10 + 49 = 59 bytes

```
a=(x,y)=>x^y
m=(x,y,p=0)=>x?m(x>>1,2*y^283*(y>>7),p^y*(x&1)):p
```

Domain is 0 ... 255. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Program_examples).

Comment: You should probably specify the range you're using.

Answer (score 4):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 22 bytes

```
[dif pro]:(ga 8 283 3)
```

Hoon already has a function `++ga` that creates Galois Fields, for use in the AES implementation. This returns a tuple of two functions, instead of using two programs.

Operates in the domain `[0...255]`

Testsuite:

```
=+  f=(ga 8 283 3)
=+  n=(gulf 0 255)

=+  a=dif:f
=+  m=pro:f

=+  %+  turn  n
    |=  x/@
    ?>  =((a 0 x) x)
    ?>  =((m 1 x) x)
    ~&  outer+x

    %+  turn  n
      |=  y/@
      ?>  =((a x y) (a y x))
      ?>  &((lte 0 (a x y)) (lte (a x y) 255))
      ?>  &((lte 0 (m x y)) (lte (m x y) 255))

      %+  turn  n
        |=  z/@
        ?>  =((a (a x y) z) (a x (a y z)))
        ?>  =((m x (a y z)) (a (m x y) (m x z)))
        ~
"ok"
```

Posting a multiplication table would be gigantic, so here are some random testcases:

```
20x148=229
61x189=143
111x239=181
163x36=29
193x40=1
```

Answer (score 2):

## IA-32 machine code, 22 bytes

"Multiplication", 18 bytes:

```
33 c0 92 d1 e9 73 02 33 d0 d0 e0 73 02 34 1b 41
e2 f1
```

"Addition", 4 bytes:

```
92 33 c1 c3
```

This stretches rules a bit: the "multiplication" code lacks function exit code; it relies on the "addition" code being in memory right afterwards, so it can "fall-through". I did it to decrease code size by 1 byte.

Source code (can be assembled by `ml` of MS Visual Studio):

```
    TITLE   x

PUBLIC @m@8
PUBLIC @a@8

_TEXT   SEGMENT USE32
@m@8    PROC
    xor eax, eax;
    xchg eax, edx;
myloop:
    shr ecx, 1
    jnc sk1
    xor edx, eax
sk1:
    shl al, 1
    jnc sk2
    xor al, 1bh
sk2:
    inc ecx
    loop myloop
@m@8 endp

@a@8 proc
    xchg eax, edx;
    xor eax, ecx
    ret
@a@8    ENDP
_text ENDS
END
```

The algorithm is the standard one, involving the usual polynomial `x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1`, represented by the hexadecimal number `1b`. The "multiplication" code accumulates the result in `edx`. When done, it falls through to the addition code, which moves it to `eax` (conventional register to hold return value); the `xor` with `ecx` is a no-op, because at that point `ecx` is cleared.

One peculiar feature is the loop. Instead of checking for zero

```
cmp ecx, 0
jne myloop
```

it uses the dedicated `loop` instruction. But this instruction decreases the loop "counter" before comparing it to 0. To compensate for this, the code increases it before using the `loop` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 155 bytes

```
f[y_]:=Total[x^Reverse@Range[0,Log[2,y]]*RealDigits[y,2][[1]]];o[q_,c_,d_]:=FromDigits[Reverse@Mod[CoefficientList[PolynomialMod[q[f@c,f@d],f@283],x],2],2]
```

*Implementation*

```
(*
  in: o[Times, 202, 83]    out: 1
  in: o[Plus, 202, 83]     out: 153
*)
```

addition check:

```
(*
  in: BitXor[202, 83]      out: 153
*)
```

More:

```
(*
  in: o[Times, #, #2] & @@@ {{20, 148}, {61, 189}, {111, 239}, {163, 36}, {193, 40}}
  out: {229, 143, 181, 29, 1}
*)
```

NB Should be able to use any of `{283, 285, 299, 301, 313, 319, 333, 351, 355, 357, 361, 369, 375, 379, 391, 395, 397, 415, 419, 425, 433, 445, 451, 463, 471, 477, 487, 499, 501, 505}` in place of `283`.

Comment: Well, here's 13 bytes less: `±y_:=Total[#&@@y~RealDigits~2x^Reverse@Range[0,2~Log~y]];p[q_,c_,d_]:=Fold[#+##&,Reverse@CoefficientList[q[±c,±d]~PolynomialMod~±283,x]~Mod~2]` (assumes that the source is encoded in ISO 8859-1)

Comment: @MartinEnder not quite sure how to implement your suggestion

Comment: @martin You can use it exactly like before, I've just used `±` instead of `f` and `p` instead of `o` (of course you can keep that as `o`, I just used `p` so I could test both of them), and then saved a few more bytes with standard syntactic sugar tricks.

Comment: @MartinEnder can get `±` to work same as `f`, but not `p` ... not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: If you copy it straight from the comment, there might be some unprintable characters wherever your browser displays the line break in the comment. Delete the characters around that position after copying and the retype them. If that doesn't do it, I'm not sure where the problem is..