# Encrypt AES256 (ECB Cipher Mode)

Tags: code-golf, cryptography

<sup>I've looked and could not find a post for this, if there is one, I'll remove it quick! [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/c-replace-aes-fips-197-subbytes-table-by-constant-time-code) and [also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/decrypting-a-block-of-aes)</sup>

The goal is (hopefully) clear: create the shortest code (in bytes) that implements the AES256 ECB cipher mode. Either convert the result to Base64 or output a array of bytes. The input contains two parts. The first part is the stuff to encrypt, and the second part (separated by newlines) is the secret key. You do not need to [decrypt it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/decrypting-a-block-of-aes)!

### Test cases!

**Input:**

```
AES Encryption!
averygoodsecretpasswordthatsgood
```

**Output:**

```
VBWQy7umRdabP1xs2y1Oqg==
```

You may output as an array of bytes too, if you wish.

Comment: Why convert to Base64? Feels like an unneeded step in the challenge.

Comment: Well, it could contain some unicode characters that cannot be seen, and that's pretty much what every program to calculate AES (golfed or not) does.

Comment: Ah, Canonical to the challenge makes sense. Wouldn't a Byte-array work instead though?

Comment: @ATaco good point, I've added that as something you can do!

Comment: Please could you put a step-by-step explanation of what is involved in implementing the AES256-ECB mode encryption into the text of the challenge?  Or/and a non-golfed example.

Comment: You should clarify that you use PKCS#7, or, and I think this is a better option, guarantee that the block is 16 bytes and don't have any padding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 90 bytes

*Disclaimer: even with clean ungolfed code, don't use ECB mode for anything serious unless you're 100% certain its weaknesses are acceptable for your use case.*

Expects `(string)(key)` and returns an array of bytes.

```javascript
s=>k=>[...(c=require('crypto').createCipheriv("aes-256-ecb",k,"")).update(s),...c.final()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BTsMwEETvfEXwJbaU7AFBL8iVUtQv6BFxcJ11ahq87q4T1K8PhiPHmXl68@lWJ55jLn2iEbdgN7H7q92/A4D2lvG2REbder7nQq0Bz@gKvsV8QY6rVg6lf3rZ9ejPqrt2ShkDSx4ro8V01eIhxORmbT62obFN0Go4nppj@jNGSo/KVMuKfJ@IRsF6ULIT@SYey8UV@a2VeX3wlIRmhJkmPfzLhyUEZAhMX3WDQqfCMU26PTvB3XNrzPYD)

Comment: May be because of weakness we [don't have ECB mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto#supported_algorithms) in WEB :)